# Bengali unicoded character showing problem

Tags: android, unicode

I have created an android application where I want to display unicoded bengali sentences.
For this I have done the following steps.

Step1: I store my bengali font named `Siyamrupali.ttf` in the Assets folder.

Step2: In main.xml file I took a text view where I display characters.

Step3: In my MainActivity. Java I wrote this...

```
public class mainAc extends Activity 
{

    AssetManager arabi_font;

    TextView tx;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        try
        {
            String str="\u0986";
            tx.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Siyamrupali.ttf"));
            tx.setText(str);    
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            tx.setText("font cannot load: "+ ex.toString() );
        }   
    }
```

Then output show `আ` Which one is correct But When i wrote `String str="\u0986\u09AE\u09Bf"`;
In MainActivity. Java

Then output shows `আমই` But i should be `আমি`

What can I do now to solve this problem. Any body give me some advice or link or sample code.

Comment: Looks like you just got the codepoint wrong in your literal. Double-check to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

\u0986\u09A\u09BF is not a valid unicode character. I am afraid why you didnot get error. please have a look on the following like

[Unicode character of Bengali scripts](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have full complex text layout support for all of Unicode yet, and Bengali matras are one feature that isn't rendered right. See [issue 5925](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5925). Sorry!